# Java & NNTP : How to post binary file?

Tags: java, nntp

I asked Google several times without answer. So, I decide to ask you my question.

How can I send (post) a binary file to a newsgroup server using Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work has ben done by the authors of [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) which supports the nntp protocol.

A quick view of the nntp class is provided [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-net-1.2.2/src/java/org/apache/commons/net/nntp/NNTP.java.shtml)

Comment: Apache code is awful for this libray, the [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/) variant is miles cleaner and easier to use.  Works fine.  The only caveat is that GNU doesn't distribute JAR's, so you may need to either build yourself or use apt-get or similar package manager.  The developer answers e-mails and is quite helpful.